# How to image Resize using imagecreatetruecolor function

Tags: php, image

I am trying to uplod full width and full height image, this is script 
but don't know where's mistake ?

I want upload full width and height (**ORIGINAL WIDTH AND HEIGHT**) image..
check below code once. this code return 600 by 400 image but i want original width and height image.

```
<?php
function create_image($file) {
    // Content type
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    header('Content-Type: text/html');

    // Get new sizes
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);

    // Load
    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor(600, 400);

    $wmext = explode(".",$file['name']);
    $wmext = end($wmext);

    switch ($wmext) {
        case 'jpg' :
            $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($file['tmp_name']);
            break;
        case 'png' :
            $source = imagecreatefrompng($file['tmp_name']);
            break;
        case 'gif' :
            $source = imagecreatefromgif($file['tmp_name']);
            break;
        default :
//          progress_log("Resize error for image : $file");
    }

    // Resize
    imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, 600, 400, $width, $height);

    $final_file = "Thumb_".time()."_".$file['name'];
    imagejpeg($thumb,"uploads/".$final_file);

    //echo '<img src="uploads/'.$final_file.'">';
    imagedestroy($thumb);
    return $final_file;
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't get it, if you want the original width and height, why are you resizing? And why are you sending contradictory headers? Or headers at all?

Comment: this script is from google, i am trying to remove resize code .. can u remove resize code which work ?

Comment: You should give the php manual a try.

Comment: i am trying since 2 hour, so i posted this question here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, 600, 400, $width, $height);
```

Youre $width and $height right there should be replaced to the original width and height of the image (width and height how you want the resized image to be).

though i'm not really sure why you want to **resize** an image to the original size. it makes 0 sense.